# How to use printf() functions with adaptative types?

Tags: c, printf

Let me explain the situation :
I have a C struct as follows :

```
typedef struct {
  int *val;
  char *name;
} tStruct;
```

This structure might be populated as follows :
- val can be null if the "val" value is not available, otherwise val is an integer value (can be negative)
- name can be an empty string if name is not available, or a filled string (not null pointer here) if a name is available.

I wish to write a log line as follows :

- if val is invalid, name is valid (equals WOOT):

> LOG val=# name=WOOT

- if val is invalid, name is invalid :

> LOG val=# name=#

- if val is valid, name is invalid:

> LOG val=123456 name=#

- if val is valid, name is valid (equals WOOT):

> LOG val=123456 name=WOOT

This means I'd need to use either printf("val=%s name=%s",...) or printf("val=%d name=%s",...) depending on the id value (so that I can either output a # or the integer). Outputing a fake integer value when val is invalid is not suitable since any signed or unsigned value is possible.

Any idea ? I wish I could avoid the following kind of construct because my struct will actually contain many fields, making too many the "if" combinations :

```
if ( (struct.val == NULL ) && ( struct.name ) ) then printf ("val=# name=%");
else if ((struct.val == NULL ) && ( ! struct.name ) ) then printf ("val=# name=#");
else if ...
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't think you mean `%#`, that should just be a plain `#`, i.e. no formatting specifier.

Comment: Yes, you are giht, sorry about this. Corrected, thanks for pointing out !

Answer (score 3):

Create a function that returns a string representation of the type, and then use it in printf

```
printf("%s", tStruct_to_string(contents));
```

Note that it can be difficult to use it that way<strike>, unless your conversion function has some static buffer.</strike>

**Edit:** using single static buffer here is wrong, because it doesn't work for more than one argument. As @pmg said, accepting a buffer is better, but risks buffer overflow, so maybe you can pass length as the argument, but now the elegant solution isn't nearly as elegant as it was. So, your function can return malloced char*, but then you have free it after, and dynamic allocation can be slow. Ufff... managing strings in C is rather painful.

The best way I can think about now (but it suffers from reentrancy issues) is having static array of strings and cycling through them every call.

```
char* tStruct_to_string(tStruct st)
{
    /* 
     * here assuming no one will call printf 
     * with more than 32 arguments of this type,
     * and assuming length of string 100.
     */ 
    static char strings[32][100];
    static int next = 0;
    int current = next;
    // here you write to strings[current]
    // use s(n)printf for writing to string
    next = (next+1)%32;
    return strings[current];
}
```

Also, the other answers provide excellent advice how to avoid duplicated conditions.

Comment: +1: best solution so far. I'd write the function accepting a buffer and returning that same buffer though: `printf("%s", tStruct_to_string(buffer, contents));`

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("LOG val=");
if (struct.val) printf("%d", *struct.val); else printf("#");
printf(" name=");
if (*struct.name) printf("%s", struct.name); else printf("#");
printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

For the `val` member you have to use an `if` statement, as the output is either a string or a number, but for the `name` you can use the [ternary expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#C):

```
if (str.val)
    printf("val=%d name=%s", *str.val, *str.name == '\0' ? "#" : str.name);
else
    printf("val=# name=%s", *str.name == '\0' ? "#" : str.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your struct has many such pairs, the the obvious thing is to break the printing of *one*  pair out into a function, and then call that for each pair in the real structure.

```
void print_pair(const int *value, const char *name)
{
    if(value == NULL && name == NULL)
      printf("val=# name=#");
    else if(value == NULL && name != NULL)
      printf("val=# name=%s", name);
    else if(value != NULL && name == NULL)
      printf("val=%d name=#", *value);
    else
      printf("val=%d name=%s", *value, name);
}
```

You can shorten the above by using the fact that `#` is representable as a string, too.

You can make it even shorter by factoring out the idea that an integer is converted into a string in two ways, but that might be over-doing it:

```
void print_pair(const int *value, const char *name)
{
    char vbuf[32];

    if(value == NULL)
      strcpy(vbuf, "#");
    else
      snprintf(vbuf, sizeof vbuf, "%d", *value);

    printf("val=%s name=%s", vbuf, name != NULL ? name : "#");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why go through all this effort to squeeze everything into one printf call? Just call it twice.

```
if (s.val)
    printf("val=%d ", *s.val);
else
    printf("val=# ");
printf("s.name=%s", s.name ? *s.name : "#");
```